# Python updating different variable instead of assigned reference variable

Tags: python, string, class, dictionary, append

Solution: `test_dict = copy.deepcopy(DICT)`
Thank you, my fellow gamers. May ease of debugging grace you in the future.

I create a copy of a dictionary, I append change to new variable.
Change appears in old variable instead.

```
CHARACTERS = ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A']
DICT = {'key1': "foo", 'key2': "bar", 'key3': CHARACTERS}

def test(self):
    test_dict = DICT.copy()  # first reference of 'test_dict'
    print("DICT before", DICT)
    test_dict['sequence'] += ['G']
    print("DICT after ", DICT)
```

Output:

```
DICT before {'key1': "foo", 'key2': "bar", 'key3': ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A']}
DICT after  {'key1': "foo", 'key2': "bar", 'key3': ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'G']}
```

The letter 'G' is appended to both DICT and test_dict.

Totally spoopy, if you ask me.

Update: I've tried the suggested: `test_dict = DICT.copy()` but with no luck. What am I doing wrong in the above updated code that includes this?

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't create a copy, you create a reference. Both variables point to the same are of memory. If you want to create exact copy that does not change the "original", you should use `test_dict = DICT.copy()`. This creates a shallow copy (doesn't copy nested dicts/lists). To resolve this, a deep copy is needed. One way to get is to use `copy.deepcopy` function from `copy` module

```py
import copy

CHARACTERS = ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A']
DICT = {'key1': "foo", 'key2': "bar", 'key3': CHARACTERS}

def test():
    test_dict = copy.deepcopy(DICT) # first reference of 'test_dict'
    print("DICT before", DICT)
    test_dict['key3'] += ['G']
    print("DICT after ", DICT)

test()
```

This outputs as expected:

```
DICT before {'key1': 'foo', 'key2': 'bar', 'key3': ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A']}
DICT after  {'key1': 'foo', 'key2': 'bar', 'key3': ['A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A']}
```

Comment: I knew it was something to do with pointers! I have a background in ASM and C++, but as Python is high-level, it deals with these concepts all for us.

Comment: However, I just tried 'test_dict = DICT.copy()' but to no luck ;(

Comment: My bad, I'll edit the answer in a second, you need to create deep copy (copy the nested stuff too)

Comment: Please check out the edited answer, hopefully this resolves your problem